# Drive JSONs from S3 files into a Kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a usecase of files getting stored in an S3 bucket. The folders follow the date pattern like `YYYY/MM/DD/HH`

e.g - `s3://my-bucket/my-app/2022/05/01/file1.json`

There are multiple such files (~200) per hour. Now I have an error handling scenario, for which, I must drive JSONs of only specific dates (e.g- May 30 to May 31 - 2 days) into the Kinesis stream. I thought of using a Lambda with the start and end date as environment variables. But the files of one hour only would timeout the Lambda (15 mins). Therefore for multiple days, it is absolutely infeasible.

What approach can I take here?

Comment: Implementing an AWS Glue job to consume from S3 and produce to Kinesis is probably more appropriate for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that works for now is:

- `Lambda A` is given the startDate and endDate. It will construct a list of strings of S3 paths with all dates in between the two given dates (both inclusive)
- `Lambda A` will publish these strings as a message into a FIFO SQS queue (so that the date and hour order is maintained).
- Above SQS queue will trigger `Lambda B`.
- `Lambda B` will get a S3 bucket and key as input (from the queue's string), and will read that particular JSON, and push the contents to Kinesis stream.